# Checkout svn using gradle

Tags: svn, gradle, ant, svn-checkout, svnant

I want to checkout svn using gradle. According to [example](http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/svn?before=1295449219) I wrote this

```
task dwnSnark << {
    ant.path(id: 'svnant') {
        ant.pathelement(location: 'antlib/svnClientAdapter.jar')
        ant.pathelement(location: 'antlib/svnant.jar')
        ant.pathelement(location: 'antlib/svnkit.jar')
    }
    ant.taskdef(resource: 'org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml', classpathref: 'svnant')
    mkdir('destpath')
    ant.svn(javahl: 'false', svnkit: 'true', username: 'user', password: 'pass', failonerror: 'false') {//this is actually line: 37 from stacktrace
        ant.checkout(url: 'svn://code.threerings.net/snark/trunk', destPath: 'destpath')
        ant.update(dir: 'destpath')
    }
}
```

But when I execute it. It throws exception.

```
gradle dwnSnark --stacktrace
:dwnSnark
[ant:taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml. It could not be found.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\prog\wint2012\build.gradle' line: 37

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dwnSnark'.
Cause: Problem: failed to create task or type svn
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.


* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':dwnSnark'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:71)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$2.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:200)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:172)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:243)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.executeTask(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:192)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.doExecute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:177)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:83)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:36)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$1.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:111)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:126)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:109)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:152)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:108)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:76)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:42)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:21)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:238)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:222)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint$1.execute(EntryPoint.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint$1.execute(EntryPoint.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.Execution.execute(Execution.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:24)
Caused by: : Problem: failed to create task or type svn
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.

        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.getNotFoundException(UnknownElement.java:487)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:419)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:163)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.nodeCompleted(BasicAntBuilder.java:71)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(BasicAntBuilder.java:86)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilder.super$3$invokeMethod(DefaultAntBuilder.groovy)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilder.invokeMethod(DefaultAntBuilder.groovy:37)
        at build_7tvcf1h4gb2jnh1u2q10f79imq$_run_closure4.doCall(D:\prog\wint2012\JTor\build.gradle:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:457)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:445)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:63)
        ... 54 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.354 secs
```

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400893/how-to-checkout-from-svn-with-an-ant-task - might be that you're missing javahl.jar on your classpath.

Comment: @martin clayton, I added `svnjavahl.jar` to my classpath, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This slight modification seems to get it working. I've downloaded and unzipped the latest svntask into the project and declare the classpath directly for the taskdef instead of declaring the path separately.

```
task dwnSnark << {
    ant.taskdef(resource: 'org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml') {
        classpath {
            fileset(dir: 'svnant-1.3.1/lib', includes: '*.jar')
        }
    }
    mkdir('destpath')
    ant.svn(javahl: 'false', svnkit: 'true', username: 'user', password: 'pass', failonerror: 'false') {
        ant.checkout(url: 'https://svn.java.net/svn/groovychart~svn', destPath: 'destpath')
        ant.update(dir: 'destpath')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I got the following to run, but nothing seems to get check out

in the same directory of gradle.build I added a lib folder with the requisite jars

```
ant.path(id: 'svnant') {
    ant.pathelement(location: 'antlib/svnClientAdapter.jar')
    ant.pathelement(location: 'antlib/svnant.jar')
    ant.pathelement(location: 'antlib/ganymed.jar')
    ant.pathelement(location: 'antlib/jna.jar')
    ant.pathelement(location: 'antlib/svnjavahl.jar')
}
```