# Why is Eclipse not attaching 3rd party libs source files to a WTP-faceted Gradle project?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, eclipse-wtp

The sources are downloaded in the Gradle cache and the classpath-entries for the source files looks ok, but Eclipse does not show the source files for 3rd party libs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/main"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry output="bin/test" kind="src" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry output="bin/test" kind="src" path="src/test/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container" exported="true"/>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="D:/Users/SSchneider/.gradle/caches/artifacts-14/filestore/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/3.1.2.RELEASE/source/bc9c347358c5d59998b27e8a13c75106c3d0696/spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="D:/Users/SSchneider/.gradle/caches/artifacts-14/filestore/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/3.1.2.RELEASE/jar/e02f3e5aa91c8caa37b2e9b780229d27e76c0f2e/spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" exported="true">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="D:/Users/SSchneider/.gradle/caches/artifacts-14/filestore/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/source/19e4dedbb956cdc3bb1d34d61a351229b653029a/spring-data-jpa-1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="D:/Users/SSchneider/.gradle/caches/artifacts-14/filestore/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/jar/2a3cfc2ea0b2c8d87f32166e16bb56e1f092568b/spring-data-jpa-1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar" exported="true">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="D:/Users/SSchneider/.gradle/caches/artifacts-14/filestore/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.1.2.RELEASE/source/49e8d929d835d4ba4556ba9d138488ecc083a794/spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="D:/Users/SSchneider/.gradle/caches/artifacts-14/filestore/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.1.2.RELEASE/jar/e43e7683289f08c1e073564a94e6f26298ec4f59/spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" exported="true">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry sourcepath="D:/Users/SSchneider/.gradle/caches/artifacts-14/filestore/javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/source/7a561191db2203550fbfa40d534d4997624cd369/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar" kind="lib" path="D:/Users/SSchneider/.gradle/caches/artifacts-14/filestore/javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/jar/b6bd7f9d78f6fdaa3c37dae18a4bd298915f328e/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar" exported="true">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>

</classpath>
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

That's a weird behavior in Eclipse with the generated .classpath-file. Just put the 'Web App Libraries' entry at the bottom of your classpath file (-> Java Build Path -> Order and Export).

The best solution is to enhance your gradle.build file (then you don't need to reorder your build path each time you generate the classpath file via gradle):

```
...
eclipse.classpath.file {
    // Classpath entry for Eclipse which changes the order of classpathentries; otherwise no sources for 3rd party jars are shown
    withXml { xml ->
        def node = xml.asNode()
        node.remove( node.find { it.@path == 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container' } )
        node.appendNode( 'classpathentry', [ kind: 'con', path: 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container', exported: 'true'])
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this something we should register as a bug?

Comment: Not sure if this should be a bug report to the gradle STS eclipse plugin team or the gradle team but it should definitely be a bug report (the 25 upvotes on the solution indicate the severity)

Comment: Hmmm, looks like this issue is no longer occurring for gradle's bundled eclipse-wtp plugin eclipseClasspath task. However, the problem IS still occurring for users of the eclipse STS Gradle IDE plugin who have "Dependency Management" set to enabled. I've reported the issue to the STS team here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3742

Comment: This is still occurring and definitely should be filed as a Gradle bug.