# Gradle dependency sources not appearing in Eclipse for the War Plugin

Tags: eclipse, gradle, build.gradle, eclipse-luna

I am working on a Java web project that uses **Gradle (version 2.1)** as the build dependency tool. I use **Eclipse Luna** as my IDE. My OS is **Mac 10.9 (Mavericks)**.

This is my *build.gradle* file (very basic and stripped down for ease of illustration):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version: '3.0'
}
```

So just one dependency, Guice. I will generate my Eclipse classpath and project files using `gradle cleanEclipse eclipse`. Then I will import an existing project into my workspace. I like being able to view the source code of my dependencies in my Eclipse projects, so I will open a Guice class, such as `com.google.inject.Injector`, using CMD-SHIFT-T. And voila, the source code of that file will appear.

But I working on a web project, so I need to be able to build a WAR file instead of a JAR file. Therefore, I am going to apply the **[Gradle War Plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/war_plugin.html)** by replacing `apply plugin: 'java'` with `apply plugin: 'war'`. Then I rerun `gradle cleanEclipse eclipse` and reopen my project.

**Now, instead of seeing the source code when I open up Injector, I will see the bytecode viewer with the Attach Source button.** Anyone have any ideas whether it's something I'm forgetting in my *build.gradle* file or if it could be a bug in Gradle/Eclipse?

Note that I am not using the [Gradle Integration for Eclipse Plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/war_plugin.html) because I wish to pinpoint the root cause of this issue without adding an extra layer of complexity to it. I have also checked other SOF questions about Attach Source issue with Gradle and Eclispe, such as [how to tell gradle to download all the source jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156847/how-to-tell-gradle-to-download-all-the-source-jars) and [Why is Eclipse not attaching 3rd party libs source files to a WTP-faceted Gradle project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836089/why-is-eclipse-not-attaching-3rd-party-libs-source-files-to-a-wtp-faceted-gradle), but to no avail.

Comment: I also posted this question on the Gradle Forums: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle-dependency-sources-not-appearing-in-eclipse-for-the-war-plugin

Comment: Seems like a bug in Gradle. Have you compared the two generated ```.classpath``` files. Is there any difference (e.g. missing sourcePath attribute?).
Have you tried explicitly setting ```eclipse.classpath.downloadSources=true``` in your ```build.gradle```. If you give me all this information and if it's really a bug, I could fix it by providing a pull request.