# Download dependencies in gradle, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I need to download the list of dependencies source jar files in all the modules in an Android project.

i tired the below code but it is giving error, as this works only for java projects and not working in android projects.

```
 task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
     into "libDownload"
     from configurations.compile
 }
 build.dependsOn(copyToLib)
```

configurations.compile is giving error, my project have build variants.

Comment: Are you trying to do the same as in the following link, just for an Android project? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281153/gradle-downloading-source-dependencies

Comment: Are you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @VicJordan No its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `configurations.compile` with `configurations.runtime`

`task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/output/libs"
    from configurations.runtime
}
build.dependsOn(copyToLib)`

Comment: i am getting "Could not get unknown property 'runtime' for configuration container."

Comment: You should be using `configurations.runtimeClasspath` in place of `configurations.runtime` for any Gradle version that supports the `implementation` and `api` configurations.