# Gradle: Attach source and javadoc to local file in IntelliJIdea

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I am using gradle (v1.9) and IntelliJIdea (v12.1.6). I have a simple java project and a `build.gradle` file. One dependency is not on maven central, so I have placed the jars in the `lib` folder.

## Problem

For the dependencies that are on maven central, gradle builds the library xml files correcly with javadoc and source (located in $project/.idea/libraries). For the local dependency (JNativeHook), no such source or javadoc is attached. As a comparison, the two xml files:

**With source and javadoc attachment**

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="jackson-core-2.2.3">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.2.3/1a0113da2cab5f4c216b4e5e7c1dbfaa67087e14/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.2.3/6021971970a43ae0c22f378cfb5813af869caab/jackson-core-2.2.3-javadoc.jar!/" />
    </JAVADOC>
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.2.3/b1c4a6c3c26dfc425efd53c00217868b60d07de9/jackson-core-2.2.3-sources.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</component>
```

**Without source and javadoc attachment**

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="JNativeHook-1.1.4">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/lib/JNativeHook-1.1.4.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</component>
```

## Additional information

The build file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir(dirs: 'lib')
}

dependencies {
    // Will be fetched from mavenCentral()
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.3'
    // Will be fetched from the 'lib' directory (see second repository)
    compile 'org.jnativehook:JNativeHook:1.1.4'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '0.1'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'ScreenShotter',
                   'Implementation-Version': version,
                   'Main-Class': 'de.fau.screenshotter.ScreenShotter'
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

My project structure looks like this:

[image]

## Question (tldr;)

How can I tell gradle to create the appropriate javadoc and source entries and add them to the xml files that IntelliJ uses?

Comment: Also facing the same problem, but with the eclipse .classpath file instead of intelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a binary repository manager, then by all means publish the module there, which solves the problem immediately. Otherwise, you'll have to fine-tune `idea.module`, either using the `idea.module.iml.whenMerged` hook, or using the `idea.module.iml.withXml` hook. This will require a bit of coding, and I don't have a solution ready. For API details, see [IdeaModule](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html) in the Gradle build language reference.