# How to specify "sources" JAR for local JAR dependency?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, dependency-management, buildship

I have a `*.jar` file in my Gradle / Buildship project that resides in a `lib` folder. I include it in my `build.gradle` via:

`compile files('libs/local-lib.jar')`

I also have a corresponding`local-lib-sources.jar` file that I would like to attach to it. In Eclipse, for manually managed dependencies this works via context menu of build path entry `->` Properties `->` Java Source Attachment. However, for gradle-managed dependencies, that option is not available.

Does anybody know how what the gradle/buildship way to do this looks like? My dependency is in no repository, so I'm stuck with `compile files` for now.

Comment: Have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156847/how-to-tell-gradle-to-download-all-the-source-jars

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use Buildship with Eclipse then you are out of luck since this is not currently supported by gradle (see https://discuss.gradle.org/t/add-sources-manually-for-a-dependency-which-lacks-of-them/11456/8).

If you are ok with not using Buildship and manually generating the Eclipse dot files you can do something like this in your build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

eclipse.classpath.file {
  withXml {
    xml ->
    def node = xml.asNode()
    node.classpathentry.forEach {
      if(it.@kind == 'lib') {
        def sourcePath = it.@path.replace('.jar', '-sources.jar')
        if(file(sourcePath).exists()) {
          it.@sourcepath = sourcePath
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You would then run `gradle eclipse` from the command line and import the project into Eclipse using Import -> "Existing Projects into Workspace"

Another (possibly better) option would be to use a flat file repository like this:

```
repositories {
    flatDir { 
        dirs 'lib'
    }
}
```

see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:flat_dir_resolver

You would then just include your dependency like any other; in your case:

```
compile ':local-lib'
```

This way Buildship will automatically find the `-sources.jar` files since `flatDir` acts like a regular repository for the most part.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I actually encountered the topic you linked when I was searching for a solution, but I thought "The topic is one year old, surely there must have been a fix for it since then..." - apparently, I was wrong.

Comment: The 1st approach seems to be no longer working. If I look at the .classpath, it's not expanded anymore and has a single entry <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer"/>. Can you confirm ? The 2nd one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use an extra folder called lib or similar on the same directory level as src or you build script.

```
dependencies {
//local file
     compile files('lib/local-lib-sources.jar')
// others local or remote file
 }
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that in my question (sorry about that): while your code works and does indeed add the "sources.jar" to the classpath of the Eclipse Project, it does not "link" the sources. So if I step into a class that is contributed by the *.jar, unfortunately I still don't see the corresponding file from the *-sources.jar, but the Eclipse *.class file (bytecode) viewer.

Comment: So in éclipse go to eclipse market place and have a look to "java decompiler" plugin. You will see source code now

Comment: I am looking for a solution to this issue as well. The Java Decompiler plugin is not a complete solution since it does not provide javadoc information.

Comment: Try this n your gradle file :  apply plugin: 'java'  apply plugin: 'eclipse'

eclipse {
    classpath {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }