# How to attach source to Eclipse debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

When debugging one of the libraries in a Gradle project, I get an error in the debugger:

> The JAR of this class belongs to container 'Project and External Dependencies' which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries.

This seems to be an illogical restriction. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: This thread may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156847/how-to-tell-gradle-to-download-all-the-source-jars