# Ways to automate svn process (using Java)

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn, commit

As we know we can perform svn operations like checkout, commit, update using tools like Tortoise svn etc.

Now I am trying to perform svn operations like svn checkout, commit, update using ant script (so svn process will be much easier).

I am trying using svnkit sdk with their given as follows:

```
/*
 * ====================================================================
 * Copyright (c) 2004-2010 TMate Software Ltd.  All rights reserved.
 *
 * This software is licensed as described in the file COPYING, which
 * you should have received as part of this distribution.  The terms
 * are also available at http://svnkit.com/license.html
 * If newer versions of this license are posted there, you may use a
 * newer version instead, at your option.
 * ====================================================================
 */
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCommitInfo;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNLogEntry;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNLogEntryPath;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNURL;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.auth.ISVNAuthenticationManager;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepositoryFactory;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.fs.FSRepositoryFactory;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.ISVNEditor;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepositoryFactory;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCUtil;

/*
 * The following example program demonstrates how you can use SVNRepository to
 * obtain a history for a range of revisions including (for each revision): all
 * changed paths, log message, the author of the commit, the timestamp when the 
 * commit was made. It is similar to the "svn log" command supported by the 
 * Subversion client library.
 * 
 * As an example here's a part of one of the program layouts (for the default
 * values):
 * 
 * ---------------------------------------------
 * revision: 1240
 * author: alex
 * date: Tue Aug 02 19:52:49 NOVST 2005
 * log message: 0.9.0 is now trunk
 *
 * changed paths:
 *  A  /trunk (from /branches/0.9.0 revision 1239)
 * ---------------------------------------------
 * revision: 1263
 * author: sa
 * date: Wed Aug 03 21:19:55 NOVST 2005
 * log message: updated examples, javadoc files
 *
 * changed paths:
 *  M  /trunk/doc/javadoc-files/javadoc.css
 *  M  /trunk/doc/javadoc-files/overview.html
 *  M  /trunk/doc/examples/src/org/tmatesoft/svn/examples/wc/StatusHandler.java
 * ...
 * 
 */
public class History {
    /*
     * args parameter is used to obtain a repository location URL, a start
     * revision number, an end revision number, user's account name & password
     * to authenticate him to the server.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * Default values:
         */
        String url = "svnUrl";
        String name = "username";
        String password = "password";
        long startRevision = 0;
        long endRevision = -1;//HEAD (the latest) revision
        /*
         * Initializes the library (it must be done before ever using the
         * library itself)
         */
        setupLibrary();

        if (args != null) {
            /*
             * Obtains a repository location URL
             */
            url = (args.length >= 1) ? args[0] : url;
            /*
             * Obtains the start point of the revisions range
             */
            startRevision = (args.length >= 2) ? Long.parseLong(args[1])
                    : startRevision;
            /*
             * Obtains the end point of the revisions range
             */
            endRevision = (args.length >= 3) ? Long.parseLong(args[2])
                    : endRevision;
            /*
             * Obtains an account name (will be used to authenticate the user to
             * the server)
             */
            name = (args.length >= 4) ? args[3] : name;
            /*
             * Obtains a password
             */
            password = (args.length >= 5) ? args[4] : password;
        }

        SVNRepository repository = null;

        try {
            /*
             * Creates an instance of SVNRepository to work with the repository.
             * All user's requests to the repository are relative to the
             * repository location used to create this SVNRepository.
             * SVNURL is a wrapper for URL strings that refer to repository locations.
             */
            repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url));
        } catch (SVNException svne) {
            /*
             * Perhaps a malformed URL is the cause of this exception.
             */
            System.err
                    .println("error while creating an SVNRepository for the location '"
                            + url + "': " + svne.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }


        ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(name, password);
        repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);



        /*
         * Gets the latest revision number of the repository
         */
        try {
            endRevision = repository.getLatestRevision();
        } catch (SVNException svne) {
            System.err.println("error while fetching the latest repository revision: " + svne.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Collection logEntries = null;
        try {

            logEntries = repository.log(new String[] {""}, null,
                    startRevision, endRevision, true, true);

        } catch (SVNException svne) {
            System.out.println("error while collecting log information for '"
                    + url + "': " + svne.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        for (Iterator entries = logEntries.iterator(); entries.hasNext();) {
            /*
             * gets a next SVNLogEntry
             */
            SVNLogEntry logEntry = (SVNLogEntry) entries.next();
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
            /*
             * gets the revision number
             */
            System.out.println("revision: " + logEntry.getRevision());
            /*
             * gets the author of the changes made in that revision
             */
            System.out.println("author: " + logEntry.getAuthor());
            /*
             * gets the time moment when the changes were committed
             */
            System.out.println("date: " + logEntry.getDate());
            /*
             * gets the commit log message
             */
            System.out.println("log message: " + logEntry.getMessage());
            /*
             * displaying all paths that were changed in that revision; cahnged
             * path information is represented by SVNLogEntryPath.
             */
            String logMessage = "log message";

            try {
                 ISVNEditor editor = repository.getCommitEditor( logMessage , null /*locks*/ , true /*keepLocks*/ , null /*mediator*/ );

                History.copyDir(editor, "C:/svnCommitCode/src","svnurl/src", logEntry.getRevision());
            } catch (SVNException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            if (logEntry.getChangedPaths().size() > 0) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("changed paths:");
                /*
                 * keys are changed paths
                 */
                Set changedPathsSet = logEntry.getChangedPaths().keySet();

                for (Iterator changedPaths = changedPathsSet.iterator(); changedPaths
                        .hasNext();) {
                    /*
                     * obtains a next SVNLogEntryPath
                     */
                    SVNLogEntryPath entryPath = (SVNLogEntryPath) logEntry
                            .getChangedPaths().get(changedPaths.next());
                    /*
                     * SVNLogEntryPath.getPath returns the changed path itself;
                     * 
                     * SVNLogEntryPath.getType returns a charecter describing
                     * how the path was changed ('A' - added, 'D' - deleted or
                     * 'M' - modified);
                     * 
                     * If the path was copied from another one (branched) then
                     * SVNLogEntryPath.getCopyPath &
                     * SVNLogEntryPath.getCopyRevision tells where it was copied
                     * from and what revision the origin path was at.
                     */
                    System.out.println(" "
                            + entryPath.getType()
                            + " "
                            + entryPath.getPath()
                            + ((entryPath.getCopyPath() != null) ? " (from "
                                    + entryPath.getCopyPath() + " revision "
                                    + entryPath.getCopyRevision() + ")" : ""));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Initializes the library to work with a repository via 
     * different protocols.
     */
    private static void setupLibrary() {
        /*
         * For using over http:// and https://
         */
        DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();
        /*
         * For using over svn:// and svn+xxx://
         */
        SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl.setup();

        /*
         * For using over file:///
         */
        FSRepositoryFactory.setup();
    }


    private static SVNCommitInfo copyDir( ISVNEditor editor , String srcDirPath , String dstDirPath , long revision ) throws SVNException {
                    editor.openRoot( -1 );

                    editor.addDir( dstDirPath , srcDirPath , revision );
            System.out.println("done--------------------");
                    //Closes dstDirPath.
                    editor.closeDir( );

                    //Closes the root directory.
                   editor.closeDir( );

                   return editor.closeEdit( );
               }

}
```

I am able to get some of the outputs as history:

```
revision: 7
author: username
date: Wed Apr 23 15:47:58  2014
log message: testing

changed paths:
 A  /testCode/src
```

But I am getting below error when I am calling SVNCommitInfo copyDir() method:

```
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E160013: '/testCode/!svn/bc/2/C:/svnCommitCode/src' path not found: 404 Not Found (http://svnUrl)
```

I am providing both source (my local system directory path) and destination path (svn directory path), what I am doing wrong over here? (Means on svn same 'src' folder exist, I just want to replace with current local directory.)

Can anyone guide me in this context?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305315/the-svn-client-svnkit-is-not-available/16310312#16310312

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution worked for me.

First call this method getSVNClientManager to get authenticated,it will return clientManager which will be used to get different kind of svn clients instances to do different activities.

```
public SVNClientManager getSVNClientManager () throws IOException{
             SVNURL url = SVNURL
                  .parseURIDecoded("<path to the base svn repository>");                    
             SVNRepository repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(url, null);
             ISVNOptions myOptions = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(true);
            //provide svn username and password
            //username = name used to connect to svn
            //password = password used to connect to svn
            ISVNAuthenticationManager myAuthManager = SVNWCUtil
                .createDefaultAuthenticationManager("<username>", "<password>");
           repository.setAuthenticationManager(myAuthManager);
        //clientManager will be used to get different kind of svn clients instances to do different activities
       //like update, commit, view diff etc.
        SVNClientManager clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(
                myOptions, myAuthManager);

return clientManager ;
}
```

**and then call method commitToSvn()**

```
public void commitToSvn(SVNClientManager clientManager)
            throws SVNException {
        SVNCommitClient commitClient = clientManager.getCommitClient();
        File fileToCheckin = new File("LocalDir/SampleFileFolder/SampleFile1");
        boolean recursive = true;       
       SVNCommitInfo importInfo = commitClient
                .doImport(
                        fileToCheckin ,
                        SVNURL.parseURIDecoded("<path at which we want to check-in the file>"),
                        "testing svn kit integration", recursive);
        System.out.println(importInfo.getNewRevision());
    }
```

Similarly we can call checkout method exportFromSvn()

```
public void exportFromSvn(SVNClientManager clientManager) throws SVNException {
        SVNUpdateClient updateClient = clientManager.getUpdateClient();
        SVNURL url = SVNURL.parseURIDecoded("<svn url to export from>");
        //destination path
        File dstPath = new File("LocalDirNew");
        //the revision number which should be looked upon for the file path
        SVNRevision pegRevision = SVNRevision.create(<right svn revision number>);
        //the revision number which is required to be exported.
        SVNRevision revision = SVNRevision.create(<right svn revision number>);
        //if there is any special character for end of line (in the file) then it is required. For our use case, //it can be null, assuming there are no special characters. In this case the OS specific EoF style will //be assumed
        String eolStyle = null;
        //this would force the operation
        boolean force = true;
        //Till what extent under a directory, export is required, is determined by depth. INFINITY means the whole subtree of that directory will be exported
        SVNDepth recursive = SVNDepth.INFINITY;
        updateClient.doExport(url, dstPath, pegRevision, revision, eolStyle, force, recursive );
    }
```