# Update an SVN folder using ant script

Tags: ant, build, automation

Let's say I have checkedout a folder inside the folder `BuildI12` and I want to update it using the ant, how can I do that.?
I don't how to create customized tasks in ant.

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean to "update the folder"? Do you mean run a svn update?

Comment: yes , I have checked out the folder and then want to update it.

Comment: My solution uses svnkit as a subversion client: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305315/the-svn-client-svnkit-is-not-available/16310312#16310312

Answer (score 0):

If i Understand your needs and you mean run a SVN UPDATE from a custom ant task, you can do something like this:

```
<target name="svn_command" description = "run svn update command">
        <if> <os family="windows"/>
            <then>
                <exec dir="." executable="cmd.exe" outputproperty="svnlog.out" failonerror="true" >
                    <arg line="/c svn update"/>
                </exec>
            </then>
            <else>
                <exec executable="svn" outputproperty="svnlog.out">
                    <arg line=" update"/>
                </exec>
            </else>
        </if>
 </target>
```

Obviously you can do more trick, using placeholder and creating dynamic task that could work for different SVN operations..

Let me know if this fits your needs..

Comment: Just a note: Using `<if>` would require the third-party Ant-Contrib library. To avoid Ant-Contrib, the `<exec>` task has an `osfamily` attribute that assures that `<exec>` only runs on certain operating systems.

Comment: I don't understand how would it work.? I mean what is the purpose of cmd.exe, will I have to write it.?

Comment: This custom target works for both windows and unix... it says, if the system is a windows system use cmd.exe to call the svn process and run the update command, fail if something goes wrong and log into svnlog.out the output, if is not a windows system, just call the executable process svn with param update, what you mean with i have to write it? Is your system unix or windows based?