# Continuous Integration - Can you call an svn repository from a build.xml file?

Tags: svn, maven, ant, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am currently building a continuous integration framework for the project I am on, and I was wondering If I was able to call a svn repository from a script, for example:

```
   <target name="test" depends="clean">
    <jmeter
       jmeterhome="${jmeter-home}"
       resultlog="results/jtl/JMeterTesting.jtl">
      <testplans dir="http://example/svn/repository" includes="/**/jmxFiles/*.jmx"/>
      <!--<testplans dir="${jtesting-home}" includes="/**/jmxFiles/*.jmx"/>-->
      <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
      <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results" value="all"/>
      <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes" value="true"/>
      <property name="file_format.testlog" value="${format}"/>
      <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error" value="${funcMode}"/>
      <property name="testData.fullPath" value="C:/TestData"/>
    </jmeter>
  </target>
```

So it looks for .jmx files within `http://exmaple/svn/repository`.

Answer (score 4):

Why, yes you can call a Subversion repository from a build.xml script. There's a few issues with this:

- How do you get your build.xml script? Isn't this already in the repository? Don't you have to do a *checkout* to get the build script?
- What if you do an update, and the build script itself is updated?
- What revision did you use for your build? The one Jenkins tracked, or the one you munged and updated? Jenkins sill say this build was done with revision 123456, but because of the changes, it might be revision 123457 or maybe even 123458.

It's always best to do your calls to your version control system before you access your build.xml file. Fortunately, Jenkins makes this very, very simple.

If you need the Subversion version number for your build process, it's available from Jenkins in the `$SVN_REVISION` environment variable.

You might say *But what I want to store in my version control system are the results of my build!*. The answer: You shouldn't store build results in Subversion.

One issue is that build results take up a lot of room in a version control system. Files are stored in a *delta* format. That is, only the diffs between the versions are stored. You can have thousands of changes in a text file, and the amount of space needed to store all those revisions are minimal. Binary files are different. They take up massive amounts of room. Even worse, their useful life is very short. After a year or two, your version control storage can grow by gigabytes with 90% of the storage dedicated to nothing but binary versions of files no one needs.

So what do you do? You can store build results right inside of Jenkins. Create a directory called *archive* or artifacts_, and copy your build results there. Then, configure your Jenkins job to save all the results in this directory.

If you are using Java builds (which I assume because you're talking about build.xml files), you can use Maven or Ant with Ivy to store your built jar files into a local Maven repository. This way, these jars are available to your other projects. Again, you don't have to store them inside your version control system.

---

### Now the actual answer to your question...

There is a [`<svn/>` task](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html), but most people find it doesn't work too well. It depends upon JavaHL and the SVN C API. Instead they simply use the `<exec/>` task to call their Subversion client directly.

The only issue here is that Jenkins uses SVNKit and doesn't use the command line client. Make sure that the Jenkins SVNKit build working directory is the same client version as you SVN command line client. You can adjust the SVNKit client directory version in the Jenkins System configuration.

Comment: This is solid advice, don't mix your build and your source control. I'd upvote this 25 times if I could.  It's like Egon said "Don't cross the streams.  It would be bad."

Answer (score 0):

According [doc](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/) :

> testplans : Use instead of testplan attribute when you want to specify multiple test plan files. This element is a standard Ant FileSet element.

So you can use a standard ant fileset for this parameter, but certainly not an url.

I suggest you to write another ant task to do the svn checkout before running the jmeter task. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400893/how-to-checkout-from-svn-with-an-ant-task) to see how you can do that.